# limit html textbox length

Tags: javascript, html

I've HTML `textbox` and I'll prevent adding characters using regex.
This is my code:

```
$("#CardNo").keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == "13") {
        $("#CardAmount").focus();
    }
    else {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
        if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

I need to add another regex part for limiting `textbox`'s length to `6`, how can I do that?

Comment: Is the element a <input> element? Is yes you can add attribute maxlength="6" to the element

Comment: You could use the `maxlength` attribute to limit the length for example `<input type="text" maxlength="6">`

Comment: See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input andsearch for the word *maxlength* to find out more

Comment: Also check the length of the value in your preventDefault if-statement?

Comment: You can use maxlength attribute on input type text. http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/maxlength

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6" />
```

It also works for textareas if that is needed

```
<textarea maxlength="6">

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jquery, besides HTML you can do it with the following also:

```
$("#CardNo").attr("maxlength", 6);
```

OR

```
if( $("#CardNo").val().length() > 6 ){
    // remove characters and show alert...
}
```